VRFV2 interface link not found when trying to deploy
Please, how can I rectify this?
"message": "Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol" not found


According to the latest @chainlink/contracts version (i.e., 1.2.0 at this point in time), the import statement for VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol should be:
import @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol;

So, you just need to add /vrf between /v0.8 and /interfaces.
